# How to set value to the bean class using struts 1 bean tag?

Tags: struts-1, struts-tags

I am a basic learner. Please sort out my doubt.

i know how to get the value from bean class using bean tag `<bean:write>`.

Is it possible to set the value to the bean class using bean tag from a JSP page? If so, how to set?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it using bean struts tag but you can use jsp tag.

The following code creates an instance of Student, if none exists, sets the value of properties and stores it as an attribute of the session object. Scope could be request, application, session, and page.

```
<jsp:useBean id="beanName" class="util.Student" scope="session">
     <jsp:setProperty name="beanName"
        property="propName" value="string constant"/> 
</jsp:useBean>
```

Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro11.html) for more info on jsp:useBean tag.